# How to express the condition that describes at least one element is negative real numbers

Tags: notation

As I have a different algorithm to be applied for negative number, I would like to describe the set with negative number as condition.
I would like to mathematically describes the condition that describes at least one of elements is negative real number.
A = {10, 0, 12} does not satisfy condition. B = {-10, 10, 20} satisfies condition.
Can anyone help me write this equation formally?

Comment: Will $\min(A) < 0$ suffice?

Comment: Alternatively, $\exists a\in A$ such that $a<0$.